# Please put Question titles back in Review

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review

I'm pretty sure question titles used to be available on the `/review` page, and we could click the question title to jump to the question directly.  Now, I am going through question reviews where the title is not on the `/review` page and the only path directly to the question is a relatively unobtrusive hyperlink, labeled "link", to the right of the question under its stats.

Could we get the question title back?

Comment: Not to mention the title is an important piece of context now missing from the review process.

Comment: Gah! The number of `Not Sure`s for me tonight took a pretty big jump because of this.

Comment: @joran Look for the link to the actual question (the link text is actually "link") on the right side, underneath the question stats.  Follow that and you'll get the title.

Comment: I did find that small link....eventually.

Comment: Titles are back now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was introduced when we refactored Review to share more code with regular question/answer display. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

I'm fairly certain this is a bug, but in the off chance that this is a new "feature", oh god does it make it tedious to evaluate questions in the close votes queue. Many times the title informs of the intent behind the question, and can determine whether a question should be closed or whether it just needs an edit for clarification.

Not having the title is a great way to get me to stop reviewing things entirely, so unless that's the intent, please to be bringing it back!

> [image: Need title plz]

Comment: +1 for "...great way to get me to stop reviewing..."