# Should not the page showing approved edits show the title of the question when the edit was suggested?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, title, review

Looking at [this approved edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6494), I see the title of the question is "How to get questions belonging to particular tags"; that is the title suggested in a [successive approved edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6495), not the title the question had when the first edit was suggested.

Should not the question title shown for an approved/rejected edit reflect the title when the edit was suggested?

> [image: first suggested edit]

> [image: second suggested edit]

The suggested edits have been approved 4 minutes one before the other; it is not a problem of two suggested edits being approved too close to each other.

> [image: screenshot]

The suggested edits are for [How to get questions belonging to particular tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146095/how-to-get-questions-belonging-to-particular-tags). The [revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/146095/revisions) shows the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [No question title in review pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146072/no-question-title-in-review-pages)

Comment: No, this is a different question. I am talking of the page that shows the approved/rejected edits, and the page shows the question title.